# How to setup Pylance (or other Linter) to check for Python 2.7 Syntax in VS Code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

All support seems to be for Python version 3. Surely there must be a way to get correct syntax highlighting / basic linting for Python 2.7 in VS Code?

I am doing a piece of uni coursework that requires us to use version Python 2.7 and want to be able to get this set up and working within VS Code for easy development and debugging.

Any plugins or modifications to the settings of IntelliSense I can use?

Cheers,

Comment: Shit, they should teach you what will be used in ten years, not what was used ten years ago.

Comment: The industry is moving away from Python 2.x for decades and it finally happened. So, if you are doing such a course that still uses 2.7, the first question shouldn't be "how to", but why? If you cannot find strong justification, then you should think twice.

Comment: there are very few differences between 2.7 and 3.x, just learn the new `print` syntax

Answer (score 0):

> For auto-completion, you can turn off auto-completions, or select Pylance as your language server as it may provide a good experience if the code is compatible enough with Python 3. We will continue to support selecting Python 2.7 as an interpreter in your workspace. For tools that keep support for Python 2.7 in their actively maintained version, we will continue to support using them with Python 2.7.

[For more information](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Limited-support-for-Python-2.7).